# Bluetooth Low Energy sample in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to c#, visual studio, bluetooth LE, and development in general. I am trying to run this sample in visual studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/bluetoothle/

When I get to the step "Double-click the Visual Studio Solution (.sln) file" I select the c# (cs) version as instructed, but I get the following (3) warnings in Visual Studio:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning     The parent file, 'Scenario1_Discovery.xaml', for file 'Scenario1_Discovery.xaml.cs' cannot be found in the project file.    BluetoothLE

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning     The parent file, 'Scenario3_ServerForeground.xaml', for file 'Scenario3_ServerForeground.xaml.cs' cannot be found in the project file.  BluetoothLE

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning     The parent file, 'Scenario2_Client.xaml', for file 'Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs' cannot be found in the project file.  BluetoothLE

I then try to continue on and "Build Solution" but nothing happens. I tried searching for the warnings above, but didn't find anything I could understand.

Edit: here is a screenshot of what VS looks like for me after I have the file open and try to follow the steps. Clicking **Start Debugging** doesn't seem to do anything but make my mouse wheel spin for a few seconds.

[screenshot of VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xY6Z.png)

Comment: Double-clicking the BluetoothLE.sln should have launched Visual Studio and loaded the project, assuming you have all the VS "Workloads" installed.
Do you have the "Mobile development with .NET" installed?

Comment: Yes, I do have that installed. It opens but when I try to "build solution" nothing seems to happen. I tried moving on to the next steps but similarly nothing happens, and no indication "build" or "deploy" has been attempted.

Comment: Could you please tell me whether you have viewed my reply? Can your app be launched successfully by clicking **Start Debugging**? If your app can be launched successfully, then the warnings do not affect app’s running. If your app cannot be launched successfully, then it is a problem and we need to resolve these warnings.

Comment: I updated my post. Start Debugging didn't do anything.

Comment: You need to set the **Solution Platforms** as **x86** or **x64**(click the down arrow in the left of **Local Machine** option) in the menu bar. And start debugging.

Comment: Thanks @YanGu-MSFT, now things are happening! :)

Answer (score 0):

The occurrence of the three warnings is because the location of the three xaml files is not the same as the current folder.

The warnings won't affect you debug the solution, because the `DependentUpon` path(open the **BluetoothLE.csproj** file by **Notepad** and you could find it) of the three xaml files are relative to the project root, such as `<DependentUpon>Scenario1_Discovery.xaml</DependentUpon>`, and the compiler can find the needed xaml file finally.

Comment: Yes, I read this thank you. I will try the Start Debugging and see if anything happens. (This is not my primary project right now so I have been slow to get back to this issue)